# Datagridview not showing the results

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

Not sure what is going wrong with my code even I browsed thru many stack-overflow discussions and is the same way that populates the result in data grid.
Can someone tell me what's the catch here:

```
 private void frmGridVw_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User ID=sa";
        string selectString = "Select Title, FirstName, LastName, Suffix, EmailAddress " +
           "From AdventureWorks.Person.Contact " +
           "Where Suffix = 'Jr.'";

        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectString, mySqlConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


    }
```

Comment: winforms or webforms ?

Comment: Please debugger break point and check what `ds` has value?

Comment: It's Winform. It doesn't throw any error but shows blank form.

Comment: Thanks it worked as I just provided the password to the connectionString.